# Create multiple file share dynamically under existing storage account

Tags: azure-storage, azure-aks, fileshare, azure-storage-account

I am learning kubernetes(AKS),

I am playing around `azure`. I have a scenario where I need to create multiple file share in azure storage account and I am able to create with set of commands but the twist is I need to create those dynamically as per requirement .

Example: I have two application both need azure storage account, instead of creating two different storage account I can create two file share under same storage account. Here I want to create file share dynamically as the application started to deploy. Because I might need 2nd application or may be I can start third application. So instead of creating multiple file share before I want to create those as per requirement.

After googling I found [this](https://carlos.mendible.com/2019/04/16/aks-persistent-volume-with-existing-storage-account/) article, but here also share name must be created in storage account already.

My question is, Is it achievable? If yes?

Update

YML for `storageClass` and `PersistentVolumeClaim`

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mystorageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
  storageAccount: mystrg
  location: eastus

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: mystorageclass
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

`storageClass` created successfully but `PersistentVolumeClaim` status is pending with error resource `storageAccount` not found. It tries to find `storageAccount` under resource-group which is created by kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. When you use the persistent volume in AKS dynamic created from the Azure File Share, you can create the storage account before, then you can use that storage account in the storage class like this:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
  storageAccount: azureaksstore
  location: eastus
```

And when you create the PVC with this SC, Azure will create the file share in this storage account for you. It shows like below in the storage account:

[image]

For more details, see [Dynamically create and use a persistent volume with Azure Files in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv).

Comment: I have created `storageClass` and tried to claim with PVC, it fails by saying resource `storage` not found under `resource group`. Do I need to specify which resource group need to use?

Comment: @HiteshGhuge No, I said it in the answer. You need to create the storage account first and then use the quote the storage account name in the SC yaml file.

Comment: Yes... I have created `storage account` under `resource-group`. but when I debug the error it tries to find resource `storage` under another `resource-group` which is created by `kubernetes`

Comment: @HiteshGhuge You should create the storage account in the group which the AKS cluster created. For me, it's `MC_charlesContainer_azureaks_eastus`.Take a look at  
 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks).

Comment: Yes.. it was searching in that group only... works by creating `storage account` in resource group `MC_myresource_myaks_eastus`. And another way is create `PersistentVolume` with same `share-file` and pass to `PVC`. works like champ

Comment: If I want to create another `PV/PVC` do I need to create another `storageClass` or existing `storageClass` will work?

Comment: @HiteshGhuge No, you just need to create the PV/PVC. Unless you need to change something different from the existing SC.